# How to find out resolution and count of frames in YUV 4:2:2 file?

Tags: yuv

How can I determine the resolution and framecount in a YUV 4:2:2 file if I know how many pixels (luma samples) the image contains?

Comment: you can't. YCbCr is a headerless format. All you can do is an educated guess and visually verify if your assumptions were correct or not. Filesize should be `number_of_luma_pixels*2`. If that size evenly divide the total file size you *migh* have a match. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [tool](http://www.sunrayimage.com/yuvtools.html) to help you to guess the format, give you visual feedback while you trying different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose to use the excellent tool vooya http://www.offminor.de/
Free for linux usage. Quite cheep for windows.

Many options to specify a raw video format, with instant preview